# Remove the boxes from PDF form

Tags: java, forms, pdf, itext

I have a simple PDF form with AcroFields. I can fill out the form successfully and create a new PDF.  However, the rectangle boxes arround the form fields are still there.

How do I make it look like a regular "flat" PDF?

When do this:

```
stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
```

The text in the field dissapears, but the "box" is still there.

I want the text, no box, and no form fields.  Just a finished PDF.  How do I do this?

Comment: How did you create the form? If with Open Office, then you should switch to using another product as Open Office adds the boxes to the content stream instead of to the widget annotations. If the boxes are part of the widget annotation, it's easier to remove them, but first let's take a look at your PDF form. Please share that form.

Comment: I used LibreOffice, same difference.  Is there a free tool that you would recommend that would take a word doc, allow me to add form fields to it, and save as a PDF?